# get the number of unique rows in the last/next dynamically generated n rows for each row in a group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dynamic, unique

I've got a dataset with group id, dates and locations.
I'd like to count the number of unique locations per row per group for the **last n1** and the **next n2 days**. In the example below, **n1=2 and n2=3** and I'd like the solution based on dynamic n1 and n2. it's a rather large dataset so performance is key. **n1 and n2 include the row's date as 1 day.**

```
data = {
        'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'DATE': ['1/01/2023', '1/01/2023', '1/01/2023', '2/01/2023', '2/01/2023', '3/01/2023', '3/01/2023', '3/01/2023', '3/01/2023', '1/06/2023', '2/06/2023', '3/06/2023', '4/06/2023', '5/06/2023', '5/06/2023', '5/06/2023', '6/06/2023'],
        'LOCATION': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A3', 'A3', 'A4', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
desired output:                            # n1=2              # n2=3

       GROUP       DATE       LOCATION  LOCS_LAST_n1_DAYS  LOCS_NEXT_n2_DAYS
0      A        1/01/2023       A1                 1                 4
1      A        1/01/2023       A1                 1                 4
2      A        1/01/2023       A2                 2                 4
3      A        2/01/2023       A1                 2                 4
4      A        2/01/2023       A2                 2                 3
5      A        3/01/2023       A2                 2                 3
6      A        3/01/2023       A3                 3                 2
7      A        3/01/2023       A3                 3                 2
8      A        3/01/2023       A4                 4                 1
9      B        1/06/2023       B1                 1                 2
10     B        2/06/2023       B2                 2                 2
11     B        3/06/2023       B2                 1                 3
12     B        4/06/2023       B3                 2                 4
13     B        5/06/2023       B4                 2                 3
14     B        5/06/2023       B2                 3                 2
15     B        5/06/2023       B1                 4                 1
16     B        6/06/2023       B1                 3                 1
```

Comment: You haven't defined the `LOCS_LAST_2_DAYS` and `LOCS_NEXT_3_DAYS` columns, which seem to be needed in your question. Also, what are the `n1` and `n2` vars? Please, detail your question and take into account the users do not have the same context as you do

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira I advise you to add the proper output without any errors, there are only 17 rows you are showing so it should not be difficult by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rolling.html) operations. Because those only works on numeric data, first [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) the column:

```
days = {'n1': 2, 'n2': 3}

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['GROUP', 'DATE'])

out = df.join(pd.concat([
           (pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['LOCATION'])[0],
                      index=df['DATE'])
              .groupby(df['GROUP'].values)
              .rolling(f'{v}D')
              .apply(lambda x: x.nunique()).to_frame(name=f'LOCS_LAST_{k}_DAYS')
             ) for k, v in days.items()], axis=1)
               .set_axis(df.index)
             )
```

Output:

```
   GROUP       DATE LOCATION  LOCS_LAST_n1_DAYS  LOCS_LAST_n2_DAYS
0      A 2023-01-01       A1                1.0                1.0
1      A 2023-01-01       A1                1.0                1.0
2      A 2023-01-01       A2                2.0                2.0
3      A 2023-01-02       A1                2.0                2.0
4      A 2023-01-02       A2                2.0                2.0
5      A 2023-01-03       A2                2.0                2.0
6      A 2023-01-03       A3                3.0                3.0
7      A 2023-01-03       A3                3.0                3.0
8      A 2023-01-03       A4                4.0                4.0
9      B 2023-06-01       B1                1.0                1.0
10     B 2023-06-02       B2                2.0                2.0
11     B 2023-06-03       B2                1.0                2.0
12     B 2023-06-04       B3                2.0                2.0
13     B 2023-06-05       B4                2.0                3.0
14     B 2023-06-05       B2                3.0                3.0
15     B 2023-06-05       B1                4.0                4.0
16     B 2023-06-06       B1                3.0                4.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
also, is there a chance to get the solution for the *next* n2 days (as opposed to last) as well?

Comment: I realised i can change the ordering or the dataset and I could get the *next* n2 days as well. Thanks again for your solution, it works great and is fast enough.